# Injecting a CSS stylesheet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a simple CSS stylesheet that is meant to alter a page's background colour however, I'm having trouble calling it via Javascript through my HTML file. I know how to alter the background of an HTML file using Javascript, but the problem is that I don't know how to call on a stylesheet to alter the HTML file. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p id="p1">Altering style of first paragraph via Javascript.</p>
  <p id="p2">Altering style of second paragraph via Javascript.</p>
 <script>
   document.getElementById("p1").style.color = "green";
   var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
   p2.setAttribute("style", "font-size: 20px;");
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
body {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: sounds like you are trying to load a stylesheet dynamically. It is a bit tricky but it can be done

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Is the stylesheet in a separate resource (file)? Have you created it as a string? Applying a stylesheet to an HTML page requires using `link rel="stylesheet"` or `style` elements; you have none in your quoted code.

Comment: your question is not clear, may be u r looking for this: in `head` tag `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`

Comment: It is a separate file called mystyle.css. I'm trying to apply it to my HTML file.

Comment: Do you want it to apply directly on load or only after a javascript event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If the stylesheet is a separate resource,</s> *(You've confirmed in a comment that it is)*, you link it with [`link rel="stylesheet"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element):

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "mystyle.css";
document.head.appendChild(link);
// Or document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
// But I don't think that's necessary on any vaguely-modern browser
```

(Can't really do a live example of this one with Stack Snippets.)

<s>If you have it as a string, you apply it with a [`style`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) element:</s>

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("/*...style text here...*/"));
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Live example:

```js
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
  "#p1 { background-color: yellow}"
));
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<p id="p1">Altering style of first paragraph via Javascript.</p>
<p id="p2">Altering style of second paragraph via Javascript.</p>
```

Comment: Although this is possible, I don't understand why you would use javascript to  load a static file

Comment: @arodjabel: There are use-cases, not least theming. The OP clearly said they wanted to do it with JavaScript, so... (Of course, they could be confused.)

Answer (score -2):

maybe you mean you want to import a style sheet into your html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/shared_libraries/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```